# Loud dull/grinding noise when driving over 30mph/48kmh

Tags: tires, noise, bearing

when driving over 30mph/48kmh, there is a very loud dull/grinding noise coming from the driver side. I thought it was the driver side front wheel bearing but a mechanic says there is no play/wobble in the bearing. They suggested the tyres but I swapped them out with some I had and the noise is still there.

This is a Ford Fiesta 2004 1.2, front-wheel drive.

Any idea what it might be?
Thank you for any help in advance

Comment: Does the sound get louder and/or higher pitched the faster you go?

Comment: Not so much higher pitched, definitely louder

Comment: Need to take a stethoscope to that bearing.

Comment: Sometimes there can be a terrible noise caused by a small stone trapped between the brake rotor and caliper. It is not released by changing the tyre/wheel, but loosening the caliper assembly.

Comment: I'll take a look at that just to confirm. Drum brakes on the back so that shouldn't be able to happen to them